# Dropping primary key from a materialized view but unable to recreate it - why?

Tags: oracle10g, constraints, primary-key, ddl, materialized-views

I have created a materialized view with fast refresh. It has a primary key (with `using index`) which I want to alter. I ran the following statement in `sqlplus`:

```
SQL>   alter table
  2          MV
  3     drop constraint PK_MV;

Table altered.

SQL>   alter table
  2          MV
  3      add constraint PK_MV primary key
  4          (
  5            A_ID
  6          , B_ID
  7          )
  8          using index
  9          tablespace IDX;
  alter table
*
ERROR in line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already being used by existing object
```

It seems that the primary key `PK_MV` still exists. However, isn't it dropped by the first statement?

Oracle version is Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle tends to do certain things in an odd way, out of pure spite, causing odd errors, and to make things worse, when errors occur, it tends to give error messages that are anywhere from useless to outright misleading.

In your case, dropping the constraint PK_MV does not also drop the index behind it, so you are still left with a PK_MV index. Then, later, when you try to re-create the constraint, Oracle *insists* to also create an index for it, and it just won't stand the possibility that an index with that name might already exist.

To make matters worse, the error message does not give you any hints about the nature of the existing object, so it leaves you with the impression that the existing object is a constraint, since that's what you are trying to create, while in fact the existing object is an index, which you never dealt with, have no use for, and probably don't want to know anything about.

Ah, lovely Oracle.  My condolences for having to use it.

So, try the following:

```
alter table MV drop constraint PK_MV cascade;
```

The `cascade` keyword will cause the index behind the constraint to also be dropped.